# Junction points(simlinks) under Windows XP are not recognized by PHP

Tags: php, windows-xp, ntfs, junction

I've found [two](http://www.taranfx.com/create-symlink-in-windows) [tools](http://www.rekenwonder.com/linkmagic.htm) which create "simlinks" within Windows XP (I know they're not real links, but so it goes).  The problem is that neither of them create something which I can use with WAMP.

Because I'll often want to link into a repository, I'll often want to keep the `www` folder contain mostly simlinks.  I'd like to do the same under Windows but while Apache recognizes what [this tool](http://www.rekenwonder.com/linkmagic.htm) creates, I get the message: `Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/wamp/www/cwa/something.php' (include_path='.;C:\wamp\bin\php\PHP53~1.0\pear;C:\wamp\Zend\library') in Unknown on line 0` from PHP and `C:/wamp/www/cwa/` is also not recognized as a directory by PHP either. (`C:\wamp\www\cwa` is supposed to be the link, BTW)

How do I fix this?  [This tool](http://www.taranfx.com/create-symlink-in-windows) doesn't seem to create something which is recognized by Apache.  Is there another tool which is recognized by both Apache and PHP?  Is this some form of ini or conf issue?

---

#### edit

The two tools above are at these two links:
http://www.rekenwonder.com/linkmagic.htm
http://www.taranfx.com/create-symlink-in-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to mark this one as "answered" because there doesn't seem to be a word-around or, if there is, no one here has shared it.

The only other viable option is to use Apache's aliasing.  I had hoped to avoid that because I prefer to modify conf's and htaccess as little as possible, but it looks like there isn't a choice here.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a hard link instead of a junction point.  You can use the fsutil command.  See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788097.aspx).

Comment: +1 for the link and for trying to help.  Unfortunately, hard links can't work for directories.

Comment: @Christopher W. Allen-Poole.  Oh sorry.  You're right.  I thought you could.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use to work with PHP then it recognizes the junction points however there is an odd caching behavior that seems to occur.